# Difficulty using listings to place comments inside document margins

Tags: listings, marginnote

I'm using **listings**, specifically **\lstinputlisting**, to integrate source code in my document. I'm trying to get the comments in those source code files to be printed in the margins. I'm struggling as the comments are printed in the margins but spaces and punctuation marks seem to be interpreted as carriage returns:

MWE

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{
  language=python,
  commentstyle={\marginnote},
}

\begin{document}
    \lstinputlisting{python_test_code.py}
\end{document}
```

[image: failed marginnotes]

Now, I can get the comments into the margin as such:

```
\lstset{
  language=python,
  escapeinside={(*}{*)},
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{lstlisting}
    (* \marginnote{\# just saying hello}*)
    print('hello world')
  \end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image: what I want]

I would prefer to use lstinputlisting, but more importantly, I would like to understand why the first example outputs the margin comments without spaces?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Use \fbox instead of \marginnote and you will understand the problem better.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer thank you for the quick answer. Not totally understanding yet, but I see now that it is not a problem of misinterpreting spaces, rather some sort of looping through the line... thank you again, very helpful.